# Order of multiplications in recursive factorial: n*fact() vs. fact()*n

Tags: recursion, factorial

Is there a difference in the order that the multiplications are done in a recursive factorial function depending on whether the last return is in the form fact(n-1) * n compared to the form n * fact(n-1) ?

```
int fact(int n)
{
    if (n<2)
        return 1;
    else
        return fact(n-1)*n;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a difference in the order that the multiplications are done
>   in a recursive factorial function depending on whether the last return
>   is in the form fact(n-1) * n compared to the form n * fact(n-1) ?

No there will be no difference

> The **Commutative Laws** say we can swap numbers over and still get the
>   same answer ...

... when we add:

> a + b  =  b + a

[image: Addition]

... or when we multiply:

> a × b  =  b × a

[image: Multiply]

Now coming to the order **Yes it will change for sure**

for `return fact(n-1)*n;`

```
fact(4) will return fact(3)*4;
fact(3) will return fact(2)*3;
fact(2) will return fact(1)*2;
fact(1) will return 1;
```

So Order

```
1*2;
2*3;
6*4;
```

and for `return n*fact(n-1);`

```
fact(4) will return 4*fact(3);
fact(3) will return 3*fact(2);
fact(2) will return 2*fact(1);
fact(1) will return 1;
```

So Order

```
2*1;
3*2;
4*6
```

Comment: The answer will obviously be the same, but what about the order that the multiplications are done in?

Answer (score 1):

According to the commutative law of multiplication, there is no difference between `fact(n-1)*n` and `n*fact(n-1)`.

Regarding the order of multiplication operations, `fact(n-1)*n` is evaluated as

```
(((1*2)*3)*4...)*n
```

and `n*fact(n-1)` is evaluated as

```
n*((n-1)*((n-2)*....3*(2*1)))
```

Comment: The answer will obviously be the same, but what about the order that the multiplications are done in?

Comment: To be clear, in both `(((1*2)*3)*4...)*n` and `n*((n-1)*((n-2)*....3*(2*1)))` the innermost multiplication (1*2 or 2*1) will be done first, then the next lowest one (2*3 or 3*2), so no, there is no difference in the order the multiplications are performed.